# How can I make multiple calls to external binaries?

Tags: process, subprocess

I want to write an interactive function to

1. Call an external binary
2. Write the output of the binary into a buffer
3. Process the buffer to extracts args for next call
4. Call another external binary using args
5. Display output of second call

Step 3 should only be called after step 2 is complete.

How can I do this?

Comment: Have a look at the section of the Emacs manual relating to asynchronous processes:  https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Asynchronous-Processes.html  For example, the function `start-process` has an optional argument to create a buffer containing the output of the external binary.  Monitoring the output to determine if it has completed can be done with a `set-process-sentinel`.  The output can be filtered with a `set-process-filter` and the output examined as it arrives ....  E.g., https://stackoverflow.com/a/42879986/2112489

Comment: Questions about "what is the best way to..." are primarily opinion-based; they are generally not great candidates for SE, but they might be right for a discussion site such as Reddit. I changed your question to "how can I...". You can choose whichever answer you feel is most appropriate (perhaps "best" in some sense in your eyes).

Comment: Is there any reason for the calls to be asynchronous?  You can do it either way, but if it's fast enough to be synchronous then that's going to be simpler.

Comment: As @phils points out, synchronous is simpler, so assuming that's enough for your purposes, the function you want is probably `call-process` - [documentation here](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_mono/elisp.html#Synchronous-Processes).